# Inequality, $\left(\frac{2}{x}+2\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{2}{x}-2\right)^{n}\leq \left(\frac 4 x \right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How do I show that $$\left(\frac{2}{x}+2\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{2}{x}-2\right)^{n}\leq \left(\frac 4 x \right)^n$$ for $x\in\left(0,1\right]$ and $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Equivalent inequality: $(y+2)^n-(y-2)^n \leq (2y)^n$ for $y\geq 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $y\geq 2$, $0<y+2\leq 2y$ and $y-2\geq 0$ so $$(y+2)^n-(y-2)^n \leq (y+2)^n \leq (2y)^n$$

Now substitute $y=2/x$.

Alternatively, show that for $x\in(0,1]$:$$(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n\leq (1+x)^n\leq 2^n$$ and then multiply both sides by $$\left(\frac 2x\right)^n$$

Note, it is true for any $n\geq 0$, not just $n$ natural.